# spaCy custom component with additional parameter

Tags: spacy

Is there a way to add an additional parameter (despite the doc) to a custom component?

More specifically I want to add some rule to a custom component as parameter.

```py
match_word = "Anna" 

def comp1(doc, match_word):
    if match_word ==doc[0]:
        # modify doc
    return doc

nlp = add_pipe(comp1)
doc = nlp("Anna Smith lives in Melbourne")
```

Problem is that I pass a function to add_pipe without being able to pass any parameters.

Any hints why this does not make sense at all or how to solve it (differently) are very welcome.

Comment: What is `rule`?

Comment: sorry, for not being precise. I mean the match_word as kinda simple rule in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to answer this myself for a week or so now and I think I've found an answer. Hopefully this still provides you some assistance despite this question being 2.5 years old.

In [`spaCy`](https://explosion.ai/blog/spacy-design-concepts#the-global-function-registry) v3 the designers changed how you add a component to the pipeline:

```py
@Language.component("my_component")  # new
def my_component(doc):
    return doc

# nlp.add_pipe(my_component)  # old
nlp.add_pipe("my_component")  # new
```

This utilizes the [`Language.component`](https://spacy.io/api/language#component) classmethod. Per the docs:

> ... This classmethod and decorator is intended for **simple stateless functions** that take a `Doc` and return it. For more complex stateful components that allow settings and need access to the shared `nlp` object, use the [`Language.factory`](https://spacy.io/api/language#factory) decorator.

While it is possible to add additional parameters/arguments to a function decorated with [`Language.component`](https://spacy.io/api/language#component), you won't be able to modify them dynamically (or at least I haven't found a way ‍♂️).

However, using the [`Language.factory`](https://spacy.io/api/language#factory) you can define additional parameters and update them dynamically (via the config). You can decorate functions and classes with the [`Language.factory`](https://spacy.io/api/language#factory), but `spaCy` recommends decorating functions. See [Can I add the `@Language.factory` decorator to a class?](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#factories-class-decorator).

To make your example code work as intended, we'll need to make a few tweaks:

```py
import spacy  # 3.5.3
from spacy.language import Language
from spacy.tokens import Doc


class MatchWordComponent:
    """A custom class that can be called on a doc."""
    
    def __init__(self, match_word: str):
        self.match_word = match_word
    
    def __call__(self, doc: Doc) -> Doc:
        # Note that I modified the below line to 
        # compare strings as `doc[0]` is a `spacy.tokens.Token`
        if self.match_word == doc[0].text:
            # modify doc
            print("I modified the doc... jk :P")
        return doc


@Language.factory("comp1")  # new
def comp1(nlp: Language, name: str, match_word: str):
    """Return the :class:`MatchWordComponent` with argument `match_word`."""
    return MatchWordComponent(match_word)


match_word = "Anna"
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.add_pipe("comp1", config={"match_word": match_word})
doc = nlp("Anna Smith lives in Melbourne")

# This will print "I modified the doc... jk :P"
```